# Processing an Immutable.js list and extracting unique objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

I have the below type script that uses immutables. I am looking to use immutables List to process the students and generate a list of students that are unique. My initial list can have duplicate students objects and I can filter them out by studentId.

**Issue that I am facing is that** , I am not able to access the studentId attribute from the Student Object when iterating the list, in line studentId is not accessible.

> if (d && !studentIdSeen.has(d!.studentId)

```
export interface StudentProperties {
  studentId: number;
  student: string;
  region: string;
  active: boolean;
}
export interface Student extends TypedRecord<Student>, StudentProperties { }
export const studentFactory = makeTypedFactory<StudentProperties, Student>({ studentId: -1, student: '', region: '', active: true });


REDUX CALL 

case types.FETCH_STUDENT_DATA_SUCCESS: {
       let fetchedStudents = List(action.data.map(item => studentFactory(item)));
      console.log("Fetched student data ==> " + fetchedStudents);

      let uniqueStudents: Student[] = [];
       let studentIdSeen: Set<number>;
       fetchedStudents.forEach(d => {
         if (d && !studentIdSeen.has(d!.studentId) { //error here , not able to access studentId attribute
           uniqueStudents.push(d);
           studentIdSeen.add(d!.studentId);////error here , not able to access studentId attribute
         }
       });
       console.log("List of unique students = " + uniqueStudents);
       return state.set('students', List(uniqueStudents));
    }
```

If I return the fetchedStudents in state.set('students',fetchedStudents) it works fine so there is no issue with the data that is being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Fist:
`d!.studentId`
is wrong, you only want
`d.studentId`

both in: `!studentIdSeen.has(d!.studentId)`

and: `studentIdSeen.add(d!.studentId);`

Second, if possible you could cast to a set which removes duplicates. Then back to array:

`let uniqueStudents: Student[] = [... new Set(fetchedStudents)]`

Or

```
  let uniqueStudents: Student[] = [];
   fetchedStudents.forEach(d => {
     if (d && !uniqueStudents.has(x => x.studentId === d.studentId)) {
       uniqueStudents.push(d);
     }
   });
```